# How separate the array into two array by the array key value

Tags: jquery

I had merging two difference array into one array and return the array in jQuery.

And here the result I receive:

```
[{"BRAND":"OHTSU FALKEN"},
{"BRAND":"OHTSU FALKEN INDO"},
{"PATTERNS":"FKU"},
{"PATTERNS":"SN807"},
{"PATTERNS":"SN816"},
{"PATTERNS":"SN828"},
{"PATTERNS":"ZE912"}]
```

How can I split this array into BRAND array and PATTERNS array by identify the key value?

I found most of the asnwer are giving the solution of looping each of the array and get the key only which is 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9...

How can I get like this:

```
if(key_value == 'BRAND')
{
//put into BRAND array
}else if(key_value == 'PATTERNS')
{
//put into PATTERNS array
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I apologize, misread the structure.

```
var combinedArray = [{"BRAND":"OHTSU FALKEN"},
    {"BRAND":"OHTSU FALKEN INDO"},
    {"PATTERNS":"|FKU"},
    {"PATTERNS":"|SN807"},
    {"PATTERNS":"|SN816"},
    {"PATTERNS":"|SN828"},
    {"PATTERNS":"|ZE912"}];

var brandArray = [];
var patternsArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < combinedArray.length; i++) {
    if (combinedArray[i].BRAND) {
        brandArray.push(combinedArray[i].BRAND);
    } else if (combinedArray[i].PATTERNS) {
        patternsArray.push(combinedArray[i].PATTERNS);
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try alert the brandArray after the "brandArray.push(combinedArray[key]);". It did not give any action for me..?